# How to replace JSON value with the jq command?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have this json file:

```
{
    "orders": "[{\"items\":[{\"itemid\":'',\"quantity\":'',\"price\":'',\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"shopid\":'',\"item_group_id\":null,\"add_on_deal_id\":null,\"checkout\":true}],\"shopid\":''}]",
    "check_voucher_payment_criteria": false,
    "need_wallet_active_info": false
}
```

I want to replace:

1. `itemid` with the value of `321`
2. `quantity` with the value of `1`
3. `price` with the value of `100000`
4. `shopid` with the value of `789`

So the result I want is:

```
{
    "orders": "[{\"items\":[{\"itemid\":321,\"quantity\":1,\"price\":100000,\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"shopid\":789,\"item_group_id\":null,\"add_on_deal_id\":null,\"checkout\":true}],\"shopid\":789}]",
    "check_voucher_payment_criteria": false,
    "need_wallet_active_info": false
}
```

I tried https://jqplay.org/s/x3IArefkyH:

```
jq --raw-output '.orders[].items = 321' file.json
```

But it gave me this error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot iterate over string ("[{\"items\...)
exit status 5
```

How should I fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is syntactically correct? value for `.orders` is not parsable via jq's syntax parser

Answer (score 1):

In order to let `jq` understand the the json string inside the `orders` element, you have to replace the single quote `'` in your json file by backslash double quote `\"`.

Then you can use `jq` to replace the wanted values by transforming the json string to object and back to string:

```
sed 's/\x27/\\"/g' file | \
jq '.orders|=(fromjson|map(((.items[].itemid|=321)|(.items[].quantity|=1)|(.items[].price|=10000)|(.items[].shopid|=789)))|tojson)'
{
  "orders": "[{\"items\":[{\"itemid\":321,\"quantity\":1,\"price\":10000,   \"currency\":\"IDR\",\"shopid\":789,\"item_group_id\":null,\"add_on_deal_id\":null,\"checkout\":true}],\"shopid\":\"\"}]",
  "check_voucher_payment_criteria": false,
  "need_wallet_active_info": false
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it'd be such a good idea, but you could use `jq`'s `gsub(pattern; replace)` to change the single quotes into double-quotes in the orders string, e.g. `.orders |= ( gsub("'"; "\"") | fromjson | ... )`

Answer (score 1):

The complication here is that your stringified JSON isn't properly stringified.  One option would be to make it valid stringified JSON, perform the updates, and stringify it again.
In the example, all the occurrences of `''` are replaced by JSON values, so it doesn't matter whether this last step (restringification) is done normally (using `tojson`) or not, so in the following, only the normal stringification is performed.

```
.orders |= (gsub("''";"\"\"") | fromjson)
| .orders[0].items[0] |= (.itemid = 321 | .quantity=1 | .price = 100000 | .shopid = 789)
| .orders[0].shopid = 789
| .orders |= tojson
```

Whether that first `gsub` should be as shown or
`(gsub("'";"\"")` or something else will depend on the processes that produce and consume that mish-mash.

Answer (score 0):

Your assinging the orders value as string. that's the reason you won't be able to loop through. remove the **double quote** when your assiging the orders vlaue like below.

```
 {
    "orders": [{"items":[{"itemid":"","quantity":"","price":"","currency":"IDR","shopid":"","item_group_id":null,"add_on_deal_id":null,"checkout":true}],"shopid":""}],
    "check_voucher_payment_criteria": false,
    "need_wallet_active_info": false
}
```

**Output**

[image]